# Add one item multiple times to same List

Tags: c#, collections

What I am trying to achieve is to add one item to a List, multiple times without using a loop.

I am going to add 50 numbers to a List and want all of those number to be equal to, let's say, 42. I am aware that I can simply create a small loop that runs 50 times and adds the same item over and over again, as such;

```
List<int> listFullOfInts = new List<int>();
int addThis = 42;
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    listFullOfInts.Add(addThis);
```

What I am trying to do is something on the lines of;

```
listFullOfInts.AddRange(addThis, 50);
```

Or something that is similar to this at least, maybe using Linq? I have a vague memory of seeing how to do this but am unable to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: why do you not want to use a list?

Comment: @RuneFS since that is how I have implemented it :)

Comment: lol I meant "Why do you not want to use a loop?". Beats me how I ended up writing something else (_need_ coffee)

Comment: @RuneFS Mostly because I knew there was a way to do it without the loop, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use [`Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx):

```
List<int> listFullOfInts = Enumerable.Repeat(42, 50).ToList();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/GN9t7C)

If you already have a list and you don't want to create a new one with `ToList`:

```
listFullOfInts.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(42, 50));
```

If you want to do add reference types without repeating the same reference, you can use `Enumerable.Range`+`Select`:

```
List<SomeClass> itemList = Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
    .Select(i => new SomeClass())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 also worth mentioning that with reference types reference to same instance will be added, thus modifying any of items will change other 49

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! (Will mark as answer as soon as I am allowed)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this will still use a loop, somewhere, but it won't be visible.

Comment: @DanPuzey Kinda hard to get around, but it won't be cluttering my code :)

Comment: Be REALLY careful doing this with new objects as it adds the SAME object 50 times, not 50 new objects.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, with reference types you add the same reference, with value types(like `int` or structs) it's no problem. But i showed how to avoid it with `Select`(last code snippet).

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it directly with LINQ since LINQ is side effect free but you can use some of what's found in the System.linq namespace to build the required.

```
public static void AddRepeated<T>(this List<T> self,T item, int count){
  var temp = Enumerable.Repeat(item,count);
  self.AddRange(temp);
}
```

you can then use that as you propose in your post

```
listFullOfInts.AddRepeated(addThis, 50);
```

Comment: shouldn't the example call be `listFullOfInts.AddRepeated(addThis, 50)`  rather than `addRange` ?

Comment: Yes it should :)